# reactjs useState and useEffect hooks not re-rendering after array data change for data received via websocket

Tags: javascript, reactjs, real-time, webhooks

I am building an app with reactjs tha needs to be real-time and I am using Rails Actioncable as a wrapper around websocket.

I can receive data via websocket after a record is created or updated and when I do console log to see what is contained in the **posts** array created with useHook but updated via webhook. It seems the **post** array is updated correctly using the code shown below. However react does not re-render the web page hence the use does not see that updated record.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import consumer from "../../channels/consumer"

const PostList = (props) => {

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState(props.posts || []);

  useEffect(() => {
     consumer.subscriptions.create({ channel: "PostChannel"}, {
       received(data){
         handleRecordUpdate(data);
       }
     })
  }, [posts])
  
  const handleRecordUpdate = (post) => {
    //copying old array
    let getPosts = posts;
    let postIndex = getPosts.findIndex((obj => obj.id == post.id));
    getPosts[postIndex] = post;

   //ensure the new array does not reference the original array using spread operator ...
    setPosts(posts => [...getPosts])
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h3>All Posts</h3>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Is Published</th>
            <th> Actions </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {
          posts && posts.map((post) => {
            return (
              <tr key={post.id} id={post.id}>
              </tr>
            )
          })
        }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
  
}
```

This is the structure of the array

```
{
    "posts": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "second",
            "description": "push",
            "is_published": true,
            "created_at": "2021-04-03T13:59:03.708Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-06-10T10:07:07.783Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "third",
            "description": "testing 1",
            "is_published": false,
            "created_at": "2021-04-25T20:02:18.204Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-06-10T10:15:18.724Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "good",
            "description": "checkout",
            "is_published": true,
            "created_at": "2021-04-02T16:39:28.568Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-06-10T15:25:42.186Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you share the array structure?
let getPosts = posts;
    let postIndex = getPosts.findIndex((obj => obj.id == post.id));
    getPosts[postIndex] = post;
This will change the state also, is it possible to deep copy first and then do the operation and then set the state with the manipulated object?

Comment: I have added the array structure @Mangesh

Comment: const handleRecordUpdate = (post) => {
    //copying old array
    let getPosts = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(posts));
    let postIndex = getPosts.findIndex((obj => obj.id == post.id));
    getPosts[postIndex] = post;

   //ensure the new array does not reference the original array using spread operator ...
    setPosts(getPosts)
  }
Can you try this, I am not sure whether this will work or not, since I am not having working code. Hope you will understand :)

Comment: You are not copying the old array, you're just passing the reference pointing to the same state array as before. Spread it to make sure you're not mutating anything.

Comment: To address the point raised, let me mention that I also tried copying the original array this way **getPosts = [...posts]** this gives a new copy but then when I set it this way **setPosts(getPosts)** reactjs does not still re-render. and also this does not re-render too in this using this new array **setPosts(posts => [getPosts])**

Comment: Spread operator will not do deep copy, it is used to do shallow copying

Comment: So you're saying that you successfully see the updated date in your `handleRecordUpdate` fn and that everything works fine until the rerendering phase?

Comment: yes that is the situation.

Comment: Can you try to run the code with the above solution.

Comment: I tried it with let getPosts = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(posts)) and then with ** setPosts(getPosts)** and then also tried setPosts(posts => [...getPosts]) they did not re-render and also did not change or update the useHook state when i checked console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue with react not re-rendering when the state is updated  via webhook. The primary problem was this line:

`const [posts, setPosts] = useState(props.posts || []);`

I changed that line to this:

`const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);`

With that change this two approached updated the state with a re-render & broadcast of the state change via websockets to other open tabs.

Approach 1:

```
const handleRecordUpdate = (post) => {
  let updatedPosts = [...posts]
  let old_record = posts.find((item) => item.id === post.id)
  let indexi = posts.indexOf(old_record)
  updatedPosts[indexi] = post;
  setPosts(posts => updatedPosts)
}
```

You can also use deep copy and it will work as suggested by @Mangesh.

```
const handleRecordUpdate = (post) => {
  let updatedPosts = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(posts))
  let old_record = posts.find((item) => item.id === post.id)
  let indexi = posts.indexOf(old_record)
  updatedPosts[indexi] = post;
  setPosts(posts => updatedPosts)
}
```

and finally this works too

```
const handleRecordUpdate = (post) => {
  setPosts(posts.map(item => (item.id === post.id ? post : item) ))
}
```